# Why Does {{#each}} Work Properly While {{#with}} Does Not?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

I am working on a project with Meteor.js and have some issue with the use of Handlebar : I want to retrieve the last item of a collection , and display the field : text which have html in it :

here is my javascript code :

```
Template.postVerif.helpers({
  'lastPost' :function(){
    lastPost = Posts.find({}, {sort:{timestamp:-1}, limit :1}).fetch();
       return lastPost
  }
})
```

and in the html the handlebar {{#each}} is working but not the {{#with}} 
which is kind of weird  seeing that there is only one item returned.

```
{{#each lastPost}}  
    {{{text}}}
{{/each}}

 {{#with lastPost}}
    {{{text}}}
 {{/with}}
```

Do you have any kind of idea why that is ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{{#each}}` iterates over a collection cursor or an array of JS objects.

`{{#with}}` just sets the current data context of whatever argument you pass to the block helper.

If you want the `{{#with}}` block to work correctly, do not return an array from your helper (calling fetch on the cursor you obtained via `Posts.find({},...);` converts it into an array).

Instead you should use `Posts.findOne({},...);` to only get the first matched result as a plain object.

Comment: Thank you a lot , it helps me understand two other bugs I had !